# How to assign country based off list of either provinces or states?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, regex

I have a list of names and locations. Most of the locations include the name of the province or state. Some only include country names, some include state abbreviations.
I also have a list of provinces and states and which country they belong to, with common abbreviations.

How do I search the text of the Location column `B` for an inexact match, referencing the names of the states `E:H`, and return the Country that they belong to column `C`?

[image: Screenshot of example data]

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP( 
                    IF(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(.*,\s)(.*)","$2"))>2, 
                       VLOOKUP(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(.*,\s)(.*)","$2"),F2:G,2,0), 
                       REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(.*,\s)(.*)","$2")),{G2:G,E2:F},2,0)))
```

[image: Vlookup in multiple columns]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.